# Why Activity's data changed when return from an other Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Sorry for my poor description,my app has a fragment in the Activity-1.In the fragment,I add some data to the object of the subclass of Application class (used to save the global data).And then intent to the Activity-2 (android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog").So the Activity-1 still can be seen.when Activity-2 finished,the error occurs ,the data I add before intent to Activity-2 are missed and turn to original state.
here is my quetsion:

1. the Application class has only one instance so i can save data in it ,but why the data missed?
2. can i save my data in the onPause()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when calling and dialog activity from another activity it's best to use startActivityForResult:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityDialog.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0); //0 = requestCode
```

and then the callback for the dialog within the main activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0){  
       // Do your thing 
     }
}
```

This should maintain the main activity's state when calling the dialog.

However without seeing your code I can't help you much or be sure if this is what you are looking for.